# Timing issues in a MK 3 Volkswagen golf

Tags: vw, golf, timing

My friend has a MK 2 Volkswagen golf with a MK 3 2.0L SOHC engine swapped in it and it runs of a charge distributor. He complains about having timing issues after a mechanic twisted his charge distributor a couple of times with sometimes the red line of the engine randomly moving to only 5K and sometimes 7k without a warning. He says when it redlines at 5K he can feel the engine becoming more responsive.

I tried to look at a mark at the crank pulley to adjust the timing with my timing light but could not find anything. How can the timing be adjusted on such engine?

Edit: trying to rephrase this question, how can you tell at which angle is the spark firing in old cars with distributor rotor

Comment: Is this the ABA engine, or?

Comment: I believe this is the ADY

Comment: this is for a US ABA engine but it may be helpful. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcp0bycftijznyd/tdc%201.pdf?dl=0 AFAIK ignition timing cannot be adjusted on US ABA engines.

Comment: it was indeed helpful my only issue is now removing the plug it seems like it is stuck is there any special tool for it?

Answer (score 1):

Friend of my had a jetta and he used to getting red catalytic converter.
Mechanic help him with a timing he said. Somewhere are marks between engine and transmission. There should be a plate or a hole under or on the top where  U can see. So much if I could help.